# Rate of SN1 reaction in derivative of furan and thiopene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, rate-equation

When I was practising questions on the rate of SN1 mechanisms, I stumbled across this:

[image]

I could eliminate options B and D because they can stabilize by only cross conjugation (if I am correct) and options A and C show extended conjugation. However, as $\ce S$ donates electrons more easily than $\ce O$, I picked C but the answer given is A. Upon discussing, my tutor said that electrons are initially delocalized in empty orbitals of $\ce S$ and hence $\ce O$ donates better.

Is there any experimental data to support this?